# How can I use the dot as the thousands separator?

Tags: powerbi, dax

My measure looks like this:

```
FORMAT( [Measure], "€#,##0;(€#,##0)")
```

It displays the numbers like:

[image]

I simply want to replace the space as the thousands separator by a dot (.)
So:

```
FORMAT( [Measure], "€#.##0;(€#.##0)")
```

Is now displaying:

[image]

This doesn't make a lot of sense to me. How can I use the dot as the thousands separator?

Comment: format strings take commas as thousand separator and dot as decimal separator. Then the regional settings controls what characters are used. There is an old answer here
https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/Thousand-Separator-and-Decimal-Separator/m-p/195511#M85996

Answer (score 0):

[image]
have you tried it out? it should work without the format function too. select your measure/column and then the modelling tab might give you what you need.

Comment: Yes, sure. The result must be formatted with FORMAT, not with the ribbon tab.